# Typechecking nested object properties with PropType

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following that i want to annotate with flow:

```
type PropType = {
  content: Object
};

export const DialogContent = ({ content }: PropType) => (
  <div>
    <p className={cn('text-head')}>{content.h4}</p>
    <p className={cn('text-bottom')}>
      {content.p}
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

I know how to do the type-check to so that `content` is of type `Object` (as shown above), but how can I type-check its properties as well?

---

Already tried this:

```
  type PropType = {
  content: {
    p: string,
    h4: string
  }
};
```

But then flow just complains that `p` and `h4` is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to send in an prop that is of type `object`, which has to have the properties `p` and `h4`?

This isn't possible without writing a custom function that does this checking. To do this you would declare your `propTypes` like so:

```
propTypes: {
  content: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    //do your validation here. 
    //Return an Error if something's wrong, otherwise don't return anything (or return null).
  }
}
```

Here's what the official docs say:

> You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
>     object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw [...]

Read more about typechecking with PropTypes on the [**Official Documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

---

### Demo

Here's a demo I prepared. It may or may not be overkill for what you're looking for, since the validation is quite extensive. You may cherry-pick the ones you need. The validations below for your `content` are (in order):

- Verify the prop `content` is passed.
- Verify the prop `content` is an `object`.
- Verify the prop `content` has an object property of `p`.
- Verify the prop `content` has an object property of `h1`.
- Verify the object property `content.p` is a `string`.
- Verify the object property `content.h1` is a `string`.

```js
var DialogContent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    content: function(props, propName, componentName) {
      if (!props.content) {
        return new Error(
          'Required prop `' + propName + '` was not specified in `' + componentName + '`.'
        );
      } else if (typeof props.content !== 'object') {
        return new Error(
          'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` of type `' + typeof props.content + '` supplied to `' + componentName + '`, expected `object`.'
        );
      } else if (!props.content.p) {
        return new Error(
          'Required prop `p` of object `' + propName + '` was not specified in `' + componentName + '`.'
        );
      } else if (!props.content.h1) {
        return new Error(
          'Required prop `h1` of object `' + propName + '` was not specified in `' + componentName + '`.'
        );
      } else if (typeof props.content.p !== 'string') {
        return new Error(
          'Invalid object property `p` of prop `' + propName + '` of type `' + typeof props.content.p + '` supplied to `' + componentName + '`, expected `string`.'
        );
      } else if (typeof props.content.h1 !== 'string') {
        return new Error(
          'Invalid object property `h1` of prop `' + propName + '` of type `' + typeof props.content.h1 + '` supplied to `' + componentName + '`, expected `string`.'
        );
      }
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>My DialogContent Component</div>;
  }
});

var obj = {
  p: "foo",
  h1: "bar"
};

ReactDOM.render(<DialogContent content={obj} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You may also test it on this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0dthcte0/1/) and do some mocking. Try changing the values, types and object properties passed into the component and read the console output.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question and answer are quite old, but for reference I think we should add the current **standard** way for type-checking using [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) which is much simpler:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DialogContent extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.shape({ p: PropTypes.string, h4: PropTypes.string })
  };

  render() {
    const { p, h4 } = this.props.content;

    return (
      <div>
        <p className='text-head'>{h4}</p>
        <p className='text-bottom'>
          {p}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DialogContent;
```

You can also make `content` or its field required by adding `isRequired` after their type definition. For example for content:

```
static propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.shape({ p: PropTypes.string, h4: PropTypes.string }).isRequired
};
```