# ReactJS: Two props and checking propType

Tags: reactjs

Situation:

```
<Component>
    child
</Component>
```

What I want to do:

```
<Component>
<div></div>
{this.function()} // loads array of components
</Component>
```

Problem:

I can only specify one propType? How can I allow two different propTypes into one?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more clear what kind of props are you trying to pass?

Comment: Perhaps [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40302064/2030321) might be of help to you?

Comment: I am trying to pass in a func type and node type into one specified prop location

Comment: @Daltron you wouldn't be passing in a function type you'd be passing in whatever returns from that function. Unless `this.function()` returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do should be fine. See this code from the [Meteor react tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components):

```js
renderTasks() {
  return this.getTasks().map((task) => (
    <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
  ));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
      </header>

      <ul>
        {this.renderTasks()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could just as easily modify `render()` to be:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
      </header>

      <ul>
        <Task task={this.props.myTask} />
        {this.renderTasks()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit:** in reply to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819643/reactjs-two-props-and-checking-proptype/42820303?noredirect=1#comment72752485_42820303) - yes you can specify alternate PropTypes as children. See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122662/327074):

```js
static propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.node),
        React.PropTypes.node
    ]).isRequired
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I also want to set the PropTypes. How do I do that if I have two different types of props?

Comment: @Daltron I've updated my answer - yes you can have multiple propTypes