# React Prop Validation for Date Strings

Tags: reactjs, date, react-proptypes

How can I validate date strings in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`?

I know I can use `PropTypes.string` but it is too loose.

Comment: Validate your props with a regex?

Comment: Well, another solution is to use actual dates and validate that the property is a date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically copy-paste from prop-types documentation using a proper regex:

```
yourProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
}
```

Remember, the documentation is your friend: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `Date.parse()` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against validating *formatting* with `PropTypes`, since it is primarily meant for *type checking* of props.

Since `PropTypes` is only useful during runtime (i.e it won't generate warnings during compilation), you could instead do something like:

```
if (!/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(this.props.date) && (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')) {
  console.warn('Warning: Invalid format for date prop');
}
```

You could put this in your constructor, for example.

---

That being said, you could still use `PropTypes` if you really want by passing a custom function. I was going to write a solution, but **0xc14m1z** beat me to it :)

Here's a previous answer of mine that you might find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302064/2030321